# check if two articles have a common tag in between

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, compare

```
| id | tag | article 
|----+-----+---------
|    |  1  | 1
|    |  1  | 2
|    |  3  | 2
|    |  5  | 2
|----+-----+--------
```

I have the two articles ids( 1 and 2). I need to see if the two of them have a common tag between them. Some kind of intersect.

In this case the result would be: tag 1 is common in both. One article may have several tags.

something like this:

```
select tag from table
 where ( select tag from table where article = 1) =
       ( select tag from table where article = 2)
```

Comment: join and count (and read an SQL tutorial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below sql will give you the result.

```
SELECT 1 FROM your_table a
INNER JOIN your_table b ON a.tag = b.tag
WHERE a.article = 1 AND b.article = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT tag 
FROM table WHERE article IN (1, 2) 
GROUP BY tag HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT article) = 2
```